# Export module correctly with working functions. Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I want to export some module to my **app.js** and use it. But i catch an exception like:

> 'getUserFromDB isnt defined'

So, that's my **app.js**:

```
var api = require('./routes/API')
app.use(api.router)
```

And **API.js**:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
function getUserFromDB(login){
  // some actions
}
router.get('/get-db', (req, res) => {
  getUserFromDB('abcde123')
})
module.exports = {
    router: router,
    getUserFromDB: getUserFromDB
}
```

Full Stack trace:

```
Trace: Trace before app.use(api.router)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\my-project\build\dev-server.js:74:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:502:3
ReferenceError: getUserFromDB is not defined
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (\my-project\build\dev-server.js:65:5)
    at NativeConnection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at open (\my-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:686:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (\my-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:695:5)
    at \my-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:655:11
    at \my-project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:71:5
    at \my-project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:238:5
    at Server.connectHandler (\my-project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:324:7)
    at Server.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at \my-project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:300:14
    at \my-project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
\my-project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:327
      process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
```

I dont know what to do.

Comment: You can access getUserFromDB function using api.getUserFromDB()

Comment: in the API.js? i tried, it isnt working. Also i tried use 'this'

Comment: No..within app.js

Comment: look at my code, i call getUserFromDB only in a router.get. I dont need to call it within an app.js one more time

Comment: Nevermind, I thought you have problem in using app.js

Comment: what you have is perfect. It should work.

Comment: can you please post your complete stack trace?

Comment: @chandrasugur posted.

Comment: Hey, posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following

```
const router = require('express').Router()
function getUserFromDB(login){
   // some actions
   return login; 
}
router.get('/get-db', (req, res) => {
  res.send(getUserFromDB('abcde123'));
})
module.exports = {
  router: router,
  getUserFromDB: getUserFromDB
}
```

Change to the following in app.js

```
app.use('/', api.router);
```

Comment: still 'getUserFromDB isnt defined'

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong. But, its working for me. I've just tested.

Comment: Can you please make sure all dependencies are installed properly?

Comment: okey, i have been trying to call getuserfromdb from another place within app.js(i didnt see these). Please, sorry for your wasted time.

Comment: No Problem. It happens to everyone. Anyhave, you can access getUserFromDB in app.js using api. getUserFromDB()

Answer (score 0):

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const getUserFromDB = function(login){
  // some actions
}
router.get('/get-db', (req, res) => {
  getUserFromDB('abcde123')
})
module.exports = {
    router: router,
    getUserFromDB: getUserFromDB
}
```

Comment: Still same exception

Comment: are you require express before using app.use in app.js ?